# OpenCV (C++): how to save a 16bit image?

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

I'm working with kinect, and I need to save RAW depth image. This means that I shouldn't save it with a conversion to 8 bit (that is what imwrite is doing!) but save it as 16 bit, without have any bit-depth reducing. I hope that this question will not be too trivial, but I'm new to OpenCV programming. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
[...]

Mat imageDepth ( 480, 640, CV_16UC1 );
Mat imageRGB;

// Video stream settings
VideoCapture capture;
capture.open( CAP_OPENNI );

if ( !capture.isOpened() ) {
  cerr << "Cannot get video stream!" << endl;
  exit ( EXIT_WITH_ERROR );
}

if ( !capture.grab() ) {
  cerr << "Cannot grab images!" << endl;
  exit ( EXIT_WITH_ERROR );
}

// Getting frames
if ( capture.retrieve( imageDepth, CAP_OPENNI_DISPARITY_MAP ) ) {
  imwrite( fileDepth, imageDepth );
}
if( capture.retrieve( imageRGB, CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE ) ) {
  imwrite( fileRGB, imageRGB );
}

return EXIT_WITH_SUCCESS;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Have you read the documentation?](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite) "The function imwrite saves the image to the specified file. **The image format is chosen based on the filename extension** (see imread() for the list of extensions). Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of **PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF**) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function."

Comment: try to save as png or tiff

Comment: Indeed, I read the documentation, in fact I've put CV_16UC1 and I saved the image as PNG. But the image is still 8bit!
EDIT: could you please tell me what's wrong in this code, assuming that fileDepth has .png as extension? Thank you very much

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Emgu CV??? I wanna save my image into 16 bit depth tiff. Any help???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the way the image was saved, that was all right (if someone will have the same problem, be sure to save in PNG/TIFF format and specify CV_16UC1 when reading).
It wasn't saved as 16bit because of VideoCapture; in fact I did the following:

```
if ( capture.retrieve( imageDepth, CAP_OPENNI_DISPARITY_MAP ) ) {
   imwrite( fileDepth, imageDepth );
}
```

But the correct way to do it is:

```
if ( capture.retrieve( imageDepth, CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP ) ) {
  imwrite( fileDepth, imageDepth );
}
```

So it was a silly problem.
Thanks to all the people who tried to help me.

Answer (score 4):

My imwrite in opencv does not seem to support 16-bit image storage. So, I used the OpenCV FileStorage Class.

Next is the relevant code snippet.
WRITING:

```
cv::FileStorage fp("depth_file.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fp << "dframe" << dframe;
fp.release();
```

READING:

```
cv::FileStorage fs(dframeName, cv::FileStorage::READ);
if( fs.isOpened() == false)
{
    cerr<< "No More....Quitting...!";
    return 0;
}
fs["dframe"] >> dframe;
```

Comment: This is a very useful feature of OpenCV, but I'm still not quite sure why they don't allow, e.g., saving signed PNGs? It seems to be supported by libpng.